# extract words from String based on such eliminator

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have this String :

```
Charle,Mike,Stephan,Andre,Jenny,
```

I just want to get :

```
Charle
Mike
Stephan
Andre
Jenny
```

So just to extract words based on `,` character, which function could do this in cocoa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"Charle,Mike,Stephan,Andre,Jenny,";
NSArray *names = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
```